# changing the signs of the entries of $n \times n$ matrix from +(-) to -(+),respectively. Will change the signs of the determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

one of the properties of determinant is Interchanging two columns(rows) of a matrix will lead to change in the sign of determinant. does it also holds for interchanging its entries' sign will change the sign of the result? how? please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. You mean multiplying the matrix by $-1$?

Comment: Use the fact that if $E$ is an elementary matrix and $A$ another matrix, then det$(EA)$ = det$(E)$det $(A)$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\det(cA)=c^{n}\det(A),$ for an $n × n$  matrix $A$

Comment: does it holds when I use $c=-1$?

Comment: Yes, it does hold